# .Net Framework Debug window is not working

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem of debugging. I have the window created with the buttons, labels and everything, but when i try to debug it, the UI/GUI doesn't show up.

I am on windows 10 Visual studio 2019, with Developers mode on (since Visual Studio is asking for it when creating WFA or Windows Forms App). I have .Net Framework 3.5 Installed and i dont see the reason why it shouldn't work. I see it every time i create a project.

The Application i am trying to create is a .Net Framework WPF

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more information - at the moment we don't even know what *kind* of application you're trying to run. (WinForms? WPF? Something else?) Do you see the same problem if you create a brand new project? What happens if you run without debugging? What do you mean by "with Developers mode on"? What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reason why the Debugging doesn't show the UI is because of the **.Net Framework you are using is not compatible with the .Net Framework version your project is set to work on**

you can set the normal .Net Framework version you want your Project to work on in the Section when the Visual Studio is asking for the Name of the Project, the Solution Name and the path. At the very bottom, you will see something along the lines of ".Net Framework". Click on that and choose any Version you want your project to work on. (**Warning Note: .Net framework 4.5 and .Net Framework 4.8 may have compatibility issues. This info is in th link below**)

You would need **.Net Framework 4.5 or above**
I highly recommend getting **.Net Framework 4.8** since it is a .Net Framework version that supports .Net Framework 4.7.2

I had this issue and when i installed .Net 4.8, the Debugging instantly started working.
For More Information, Check out this Link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.5-4.8

**[18th April 2022] - Edit:** .Net 6 is a thing. You can use that instead of **.Net Framework 4.8**